# ByteArray - string comparison, without using bytearray.tostring()

Tags: java, string, arrays

I am using Java for a map reduce programming.

I have a byte Array with 10 MB data in it. I want to compare each byte to see if it is a space or not, my basic purpose is to get each word in this byte array, by separating the words using space (that is my idea, any other suggestion is welcome). I can for sure do it using string, i.e first converting the whole byte array to string, then comparing and then doing a substring to get each word, but this duplicates the data. I don't want anything that creates a duplicate like stringbuilder, StringTokenizer, substring.

I want each word in the bytearray, but without any duplicates since I am doing in memory computing and duplicates make me run out of resources. Any suggestion/idea how to proceed would be appreaciated.

Comment: If I've got you correctly, you can read the file byte by byte and compare it the ASCII code corresponding to space.

Comment: You can't do that. You are not sure what character coding this byte array represents. It does happen that in _some_ encodings there is a 1-1 byte<->char numeric mapping for space characters, but do you want to rely on that?

Comment: So probably, i can have a check for what encoding is being used, and based on that i can use char by char ASCII code comparison...am browsing on how to do it... I guess i can try to have a function like byteArray.getCharAt(pos), which checks the charAt position to be ASCII for space

Comment: Any idea on how to get the encoding of byteArray obtained by doing a string.getBytes() ?

Comment: "Any idea on how to get the encoding of byteArray obtained by doing a string.getBytes()?" You can but it's not easy... Where does this 10 MiB byte array come from to start with?

Comment: I have a normal text file which I have read using this function: 
public static byte[] transFile(File args) throws IOException {

  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args);
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

  for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
   bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
  }
  return bos.toByteArray();
 }

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting, I have no idea how to do it here !!  :D

Comment: OK, so you get a byte array; do you have any idea of the encoding used to write the text into that file to begin with?

Comment: I tried to change the code and got the encoding now, which is ASCII(but not using previous code given, I use InputStream now, just for ease..), Now I want to get the ASCII of each byte in the byteArray..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid creating a String for the whole array (and strings for the words are OK), you could do

```
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
int pos = 0;
int len = byteArray.length;
for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
  if (i == len || byteArray[i] == ' ') {
    if (i > pos + 1) {
      String word = new String(byteArray, pos, i - pos, "UTF-8");
      words.add(word);
    }
    pos = i + 1;
  }
}
```

p.s. Your comment seems to suggest that you read the byte array from a file. Why not avoid that and read the words from the file directly? If you can use a newline (\n) as the delimiter (instead of a space), you could just do something like this:

```
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args), "UTF-8"));
while (true) {
  String word = reader.readLine();
  if (word == null) {
    break;
  }
  words.add(word);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: nice explanation, thanks, but I am not using readLine() because I have another idea to use parallel programming.. thanks anyways :)